# Clear Activity Stack for Application from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, accountmanager

I have gone through numerous similar links before putting this question here but could not find a suitable solution.

My Requirement is as follows:
I am using Android's AccountManager to maintain the user Accounts. There can be a scenario when my app is in background, user goes to Settings -> Accounts -> Deletes the account for my App. In such scenario, I need to remove the user data(Needs to be done even if Application is not running). Also need to  clear the activity stack if Application is running in background. When the user goes back to my application, it should be opened like new launch.

I have declared BroadcastReceiver in Manifest for receiving the AccountManager Change Updates.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now when onReceive of MyBroadcastReceiver is invoked, I have done the Account related handling. Now I want to remove the Activity stack of my app. So that when user restores the app, last opened Activity should not be reopened as it might be irrelevant now.

All the solutions that I found used finish() inside the Activity but in this case I have to finish my App Activities from Broadcast receiver invoked by framework.

Comment: you can use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` in application class, check user state in onResume, then start you `HomeActivity` with `clearTop` flag if you need to restart application.